# Sharing Webstorm Node.js Environment Variables

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I have a growing list of environment variables for my Node.js app in webstorm.  Is there a way to share this list so that any new developers we have to the project do not need to manually add them but can rather just import them?  As we add db connections or api keys that we don't want to be part of the codebase it would make things much easier to just be able to add those and then easily share the file with all of the team.

Comment: Are you familiar with writing node modules? For your variables files you could do `module.exports = { var1: "value", var2: "value"}` and then other devs can get these values by using `require(varfile);`

Comment: Do you actually mean sharing Node.js Run configurations (with environment variables set up)? It can be done easily - just tick the 'Share' checkbox in your Run configuration to get it stored in your project directory, .idea/runConfigurations/<your_config_name>.xml. You can then commit this file to version control to make it available to your co-workers

Comment: That share button is exactly what I was looking for.  We don't actually include the .idea folder in our source control but I can at least share this file and we can manage changes in that with process.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy all `env` variables out of a shared text file and paste it into the `env` vars window via the **Paste button**

[image]